# Tsung cluster issues: can't start tsugn cluster

Tags: load, erlang, load-testing, tsung

I'm asking this question because I tried the other solutions already posted here.  I have a Tsung cluster I'm attempting to setup using EC2 instances.

The security group for the EC2 boxes has already opened ports 0-65335.

Master box:
can ssh into client boxes as root
"StrictHostKeyChecking no" in /etc/ssh/ssh_config
cluster box, tsungcluster1 is in /etc/hosts file with ipaddress.

Tsung xml file is setup as:

`<client host="tester0" weight="8" maxusers="10000" cpu="4"/>`

running Tsung results in:

`Can't start newbeam on host 'XXXXX (reason: timeout) ! Aborting!`

as well, trying out:

`slave:start(tester0,root,"-setcookie mycookie").`

results in `{error,timeout}`

Like I've said, I've tried out the solutions posted here previously, but none worked.

Comment: before i forget, i'm using Tsung 1.4.2, and Erlang V5.8.5 (R14 i believe)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is on ssh communication between the controller and the slave, you can have a look at http://tsung.erlang-projects.org/user_manual.html#htoc82 wich it's explain the problem you encounter.